# How do I connect to SSH over an existing OpenVPN connection?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I have a dedicated server running OpenVPN and SSH on Ubuntu 14.04. Sometimes, port 22 is blocked on a remote network, while OpenVPN can still be used. So how do I manage to connect to SSH over the established OpenVPN connection to the server?

Both services are running on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

With OpenVPN and SSH on the same host, you can use his IP on the vpn subnet.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to the VPN, you get the IP from the VPN server, that makes you appear local to the remote network your VPN client connected to.

So when you ssh you are as free to ssh as any computer on the network you connected to.

You are not clear when you say both services are running on the same machine. Both involve a client and a server on different machines.   So if the network you connect to over the VPN has a computer running an SSH server. And if the computer you connect from runs a VPN client that enables you to connect to the VPN server. And if the computer you connect to runs an SSH client. i.e. your computer has an SSH client and VPN client.  And a computer on the remote network has an SSH server and VPN server. Then you connect.

You are talking about your computer, and a remote network, so if you say something is running on "the same machine" it's not clear what machine you are talking about. There are a number of machines.And you need a client as well as a service/server.

Answer (score 0):

For SSH through the VPN tunnel: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069846/connected-to-openvpn-server-but-cant-ssh

On the Openvpn host:

```bash
$ sudo ufw enable    
$ sudo ufw allow 1194/udp comment "Allowing OpenVPN Connections"    
$ sudo ufw allow from 10.8.0.1/24 to any port 22 proto tcp comment "SSH allowed for VPN clients"
```

On the client side:

Make sure OpenSSH is installed and running and port 22 is open on the firewall.